# Websphere API to read MQ queue names

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq

I want to write a utility to check if the MQ is configured correctly. I want to see if `ConnectionManager`, `QueueName`, etc., other configurations are configured correctly in different ENVs. Can somebody give me some sample to do this. Not much is available on net most of them speak about connection to queues and consuming or producing the messages like [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jms/j-jms-updated.html).

Basically I want to read the meta-information and not the actual data or messages.

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
cf.setHostName(WMQ_HOST);
cf.setPort(WMQ_PORT);
cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);

MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

till here looks fine. Now I want read the other information like I said; am I totally wrong ?. Kindly suggest.

Comment: You have an answer to use PCF interface. Bear in mind however that not all configuration is available through the command server, some is in ini files which require you to be on the box. You may be better off with a script to do this than an application program too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're collecting stats, check out this groovy script: https://github.com/nickman/HeliosStreams/blob/master/collector-server/src/test/resources/mq/mq-5s.groovy

Comment: Trying to run this script. Added the jar in /ext folder of soap-ui. Still see the same exception. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The API you want to look at is called the *PCF* API. It's not the easiest API to use, but once you get used to it, it's ok. I started a project to provide a simplification wrapper, https://github.com/nickman/easymq, but I don't work with MQ anymore. Perhaps the source will be useful to you. Also check the MQ docs for PCF Command Reference.

Comment: Going through  API, it might take a while and I don't need it anymore after this stats project. So using your github API can you give me a sample to collect information about `queue` like name, etc., the once which am looking for.